# Bath tub install with dry wall in place

Tags: bathtub

What are the techniques to get a tub into the alcove during a remodel.

The alcove is 60", but with the drywall, (ahead of the alcove), the width is only 59"

Thank you

Comment: Methinks you'll be removing some drywall that was installed too soon.

Comment: is the 59" measurement somehow important?

Comment: This is a remodel, so the dry wall is existing.  Everything is the alcove has been removed, exposing the 60" width between the studs.  The studs inside the alcove are 60"; if you subtract the drywall thickness, the leaves 59".  Thus eliminating laying the tub on the subfloor and sliding it in.  I was just looking for some technique others may have used.  Thank you

Comment: I do not understand this aversion to cutting or removing a section of drywall or backer board to expose the plumbing, a leak, the electrical box, etc. to do a job properly.  I understand if the finish is unique or special,  OP would probably be better position if the drywall is removed, tub slid in, and new solid drywall reinstalled to the proper height of the tub unless their is a compelling reason not to remove the drywall above the tub.  Installing fresh drywall will not take that long.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact shape you might be able to tilt it up (about 1 degree, or considerably more based on what the lip shape is) at one end if there's enough room to rotate it back down once "in place" but tubs are awkward to fiddle into place and redoing the drywall after it's in might be simpler (or just needed even if you don't remove it first, from the scars you'll probably put into it fighting with the tub.)

Comment: Yeah, I'd say the odds of dinging the drywall are great enough that trying to maneuver a tub around it isn't going to be worth the effort. No indication of what the tub's made of, but if it's heavy it won't be fun.

Comment: Tub is acrylic.